# How to get a value once of a firebase database (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just started using firebase and I'm amazed of how simple are complex things, and how complex simple things can be.

I need to check if a user exists in my Firebase database, and if exists, I need to get its key and value.

I have the key and I try to find it in the DB by going to my user subtree and loking for a child with the same key (ID)

```
DatabaseReference root_firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference users_firebase = root_firebase.child("Users");
DatabaseReference friend_found = users_firebase.child(key_searched_friend);
```

once I have it I try to call some method like

```
friend_found.getValue();
```

or

```
friend_found.child("user_name").getValue();
```

But it does not exist,

this seems weird since I can do both

```
friend_found.getKey();
friend_found.child("user_name").getKey();
```

I can't do this with the overriden method onDataChanged() since the data does not change when I query for this value.

This is my firebase database structure:

```
{
  "RoomNames" : {
    "Room-KM5cof0jcoMN8a4g6vC" : {
      "room_name" : "TESTrOOM"
    },
    "Room-KM5dg_WPRdEOT4_oJ1r" : {
      "room_name" : "testRoom2"
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "User-KM5ZaGq0xvjQis05CPF" : {
      "user_name" : "Enrique"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say: *I can't do this with the overriden method onDataChanged() since the data does not change when I query for this value*

The guide for how to [Retrieve Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data) explains that:

> Firebase data is retrieved by attaching an asynchronous listener to a
>   FirebaseDatabase reference. The listener is triggered **once for the
>   initial state** of the data and again anytime the data changes.

So when you attach a listener to a location, [onDataChanged()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener) fires and gives you the current value.

In the section titled Read Data Once, the guide states:

> In some cases you may want a callback to be called once and then
>   immediately removed, such as when initializing a UI element that you
>   don't expect to change. You can use the
>   **addListenerForSingleValueEvent()** method to simplify this scenario: it
>   triggers once and then does not trigger again.

Comment: I don't understand how this would be useful, since every time a user is added to the database it would also add it as a friend, other nosql DB let me use .getValue() or .exists() in any part of the DB I don't see any advantage on blocking this functionality, although I'm sure they are.

Comment: also the code from their own documentation doesn't even compile [linkToTheirCode](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-reading-once), it complains that onClancelled has to be implemented and then that onCancelled can't be overwritten.
`Error:(143, 88) error: <anonymous urba.com.corcel.Views.EditProfile$3$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onCancelled(DatabaseError) in ValueEventListener
Error:(148, 21) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`

Comment: Your link is to the old documentation.  If you are using Firebase 9.x.x you want to reference the [new documentation for ValueEventListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener).  The parameter type for `onCancelled()` changed.

Comment: It works, at least it compiles, my problem now, it's that since onDataChanged() is asynchronous, it runs after I try to add the friend, is there a easy way to avoid this?
I'm trying to make it wait with 
`task.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`
But I don't know in wich method I should call it or how

Answer (score 2):

Use as below :

```
friend_found.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                 String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Error while reading data");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For a database reference object, the same way one can add an event listener, it can also be removed, using `removeEventListener`.

Instead of creating an anonymous object like this

```
    friend_found.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Error while reading data");
            }
    });
```

you can create a named object of `ValueEventListener` and remove it from the database reference object using `removeEventListener`, at the end of the `onDataChange` method

```
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                    friend_found.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Error while reading data");
            }
    });

    friend_found.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

The code inside `onDataChange` method gets executed only once as the `ValueEventListener` object is removed as soon as the last line of the method gets executed.