# (Kotlin) I want to retrieve data from realtime database(firebase) without using addValueEventListener

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get data from firebase and put into array to make a list for recyclerView.
In database, there are news title, img source and link.

```
val firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val rootRef: DatabaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("20210107")
val justList = ArrayList<justInfo>()
rootRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot){
        var title : String = snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString()
        var link : String = snapshot.child("link").getValue().toString()
        var imgSrc: String = snapshot.child("img").getValue().toString()
        justList.add(justInfo(title, link, imgSrc))
    }
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError){
    }
})
```

I don't want to detect the change on Database. I just want to pull existing data from DB.
What should I do?

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage())`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a value once of a firebase database (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255513/how-to-get-a-value-once-of-a-firebase-database-android)

Comment: thanks I solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice to meet Korean on stackOverflow.

I can't write down the answer as Korean, so I am writing down the answer in English.

If you want to detect data for once, you can use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`.

`addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` can be used when you need one callback.

You can check the Korean Tistory blog, which has a good explain.

https://stack07142.tistory.com/282

Also the official docs might be helpful.

If you have any more question, please don't hesitate to write a comment.

Gam sa hap ni da

Comment: I did it Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer loading the data once and never, try using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener`.

```
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{

//rest of the code remains the same
   ...
   ...
   ...
})
```

check the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once) for more info

Comment: I did it Thank you